# Calculate Shortest distance between points on a 2d grid, Python

Tags: python, sorting

Giving the following data frame.

```
names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']
x = [3, 6, 6, 10, 12, 15, 3, 6, 13, 9, 13, 12]
y = [9, 12, 9, 9, 12, 9, 6, 3, 8, 3, 1, 3]
```

goal: My goal is to find the shortest path between starting point 'a' to last point, following my algorithm which goes like this, i take first point 'a' and find its closest 3 points for example 'b, c and d' and calculate the distance between a and d like this dist1 = abcd and dist2 = acbd if acbd is shorter than i take the point 'c' as the next hop if not then b is the next hop, then i move to the next point 'b' assuming 'b' is the closest to a.

I have come very close to solving it but its seems i have some logical error as the final list that have jumping points has duplicated points.

my code:

```
def distance(p1, p2):
    return math.sqrt((p2[0] - p1[0])**2 + (p2[1] - p1[1])**2)


def get_hops():
    hopes = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(len(y)):
            dist = distance((x[i], y[i]), (x[j], y[j]))
            hopes.append({'from': names[i], 'to': names[j], 'dist': dist})
    return hopes


def get_points(points):
    point_1 = points[0]
    point_2 = points[0]
    point_3 = points[0]
    for point in points:
        if point['dist'] < point_1['dist']:
            point_1 = point

        if point['dist'] < point_2['dist'] and point['to'] != point_1['to']:
            point_2 = point

        if point['dist'] < point_3['dist'] and point['to'] != point_1['to'] and point['to'] != point_2['to']:
            point_3 = point

    return point_1, point_2, point_3


def get_optimal_path(names_list):
    backup_list = []
    for elm in names_list:
        backup_list.append(elm)
    points_list = [names_list[0]]
    backup_list.remove(names_list[0])
    hops = get_hops()
    for elm in itertools.cycle(names_list):
        if len(points_list) != len(backup_list)-3:
            print(elm, points_list[-1])
            if elm == points_list[-1]:

                # get closet 3 points to the last point in path
                hop_1 = {'from': 'qdsofhvcl', 'to': 'qjf', 'dist': 10000000000000}
                hop_2 = {'from': 'qdsofhvcl', 'to': 'qjf', 'dist': 10000000000000}
                hop_3 = {'from': 'qdsofhvcl', 'to': 'qjf', 'dist': 10000000000000}
                for hop in hops:
                    if hop['from'] == elm and hop['to'] != elm and hop['dist'] < hop_1['dist']:
                        hop_1 = hop

                for hop in hops:
                    if hop['from'] == elm and hop['to'] != elm and hop['dist'] < hop_2['dist'] and hop['to'] != hop_1['to']:
                        hop_2 = hop

                for hop in hops:
                    if hop['from'] == elm and hop['to'] != elm and hop['dist'] < hop_3['dist'] and hop['to'] != hop_1['to'] and hop['to'] != hop_2['to']:
                        hop_3 = hop

                # calculate dist_1 and dist_2 to determine optimal hoping point
                dist_1 = 0
                dist_2 = 0
                for hop in hops:
                    if hop['from'] == elm and hop['to'] == hop_1['to']:
                        dist_1 += hop['dist']
                    if hop_1['from'] == hop['from'] and hop_2['to'] == hop['to']:
                        dist_1 += hop['dist']
                    if hop_2['to'] == hop['from'] and hop['to'] == hop_3['to']:
                        dist_1 += hop['dist']

                    if hop['from'] == elm and hop['to'] == hop_2['to']:
                        dist_2 += hop['dist']
                    if hop_2['to'] == hop['from'] and hop_1['to'] == hop['to']:
                        dist_2 += hop['dist']
                    if hop_1['to'] == hop['from'] and hop['to'] == hop_3['to']:
                        dist_2 += hop['dist']

                # compare 2 distances and determine the best hoping point
                if dist_1 < dist_2:
                    points_list.append(hop_1['to'])
                    print(backup_list)
                    # backup_list.remove(hop_1['to'])
                else:
                    points_list.append(hop_2['to'])
                    print(backup_list)
                    # backup_list.remove(hop_2['to'])
        else:
            print('exit')
            break
        print(points_list)
```

Any piece of advice is much appreciated, i am open to new methods of sorting if they are available but my algorithm is a priority.

Thanks.

Comment: The goal isn't clear, you should rewrite the paragraph.

Comment: The code isn't clear as well. Don't you prefer to define a `Point` class with attributes `x`, `y`, and a `def distance(other: Point)`?

Comment: @Demi-Lune I have edited the question, please see if the goal is clear now.

Comment: @ItayB i agree its better for code organization, but will it help me find the issue ?

Comment: In my opinion, yes. Readable code is easier to debug/maintain. You can then use build in `sort` method to etc.

Comment: It is a little better, but the goal is still not clear. Are you trying to go from 'a' to 'l'? Or through all the points?  Looking for the shortest overall path? Or the shortest hops? Why do you need those 3 closest points, when you seem to go for the closest anyways?

Comment: By the way, `names` repeats `'b'` twice.

Comment: You should also add a test case...

Comment: @Demi-Lune i choose the next hop based on the distance from starting point to the third closest point that way i am sure to get the optimal next hop not just based on the distance between the points.

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel here. From your description I am a little unsure on what you need exactly but this may work:  [Dijkstra's Algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-greedy-algo-7/). You can also look up more graph algorithms and find the one that fits your needs.

Edit: Yes it will return a path that connects all the points to the source vertex in the shortest distance

Comment: ok i have learned about the dijkstra algorithm and have one question, will it return a path that connect all points given to it ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).